# Insert statement in except block in redshift plpgsql

Tags: amazon-redshift, plpgsql

I have a procedure which performs inserts and updates a number of tables. I want to have an exception block where I can store all the
Query errors.
I tried to find some solutions and saw that maybe it was not possible to 
Use dml statements in except block.
Need some help please. Is it really possible or please suggest an alternate solution.

Comment: Hi Avishek. From your description is not completely clear what you want to implement. I'm not an expert on pl pg sql, but found some references on exception handling. However, "I think" you need something beyond an exception. Perhaps if you show some code it would be easier to understand what is your problem and what do you want to accomplish?

Comment: please try to follow this guidance https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example